# Maven не видит пакет junit

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven, junit

При запуске команды mvn clean verify, мавен ругается что не может найти junit, хотя папки не менял, и сами тесты проходят, т.е., фактически то он видит, но не видит.
Я еще очень новичок во всем этом и не понимаю половину того что я делаю)
Сам файл pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

4.0.0

```
<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<artifactId>JavaQAhw12.1</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>5.9.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <failIfNoTests>true</failIfNoTests>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>


        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>prepare-agent</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>report</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>check</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <rules>
                            <rule>
                                <limits>
                                    <limit>
                                        <counter>BRANCH</counter>
                                        <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                        <minimum>100%</minimum>
                                    </limit>
                                </limits>
                            </rule>
                        </rules>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Сама ошибка [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытался найти на сайте и в интернете, обычно такая ошибка возникала если в зависимости указывали другой путь к папке тест, меняли его, но у меня он стоит как всегда один и тот же, и вот впервые вылезло что то не то.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: 1. Добавьте код класса AfishaManagerTest. 2. Никогда не вставляйте текст картинкой.

Comment: `org.junit` - это пакет из junit4. У вас в зависимостях проекта junit5, у него `@Test` находится в другом пакете - используйте `import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test` вместо `import org.junit.Test;`. Либо с зависимостях проекта используйте junit4.